# Database Sync failing after a day

Tags: azure-sql-database

We setup database sync between two databases on the same server. It worked fine yesterday and then stopped working today. I tried killing connections to the database and stopping the web apps that are connected to the database thinking maybe it was a connection limit. I also reset the user and pass after verifying the connection is correct.

This is the error we're getting:

`Database re-provisioning failed with the exception "The current operation could not be completed because the database is not provisioned for sync or you not have permissions to the sync configuration tables."    For more information, provide tracing ID ‘b4b76a8c-38ae-4b48-ad08-6c07933c23c1’ to customer support.`

Answer (score 1):

The error log indicated that the previously provision related operation was not completed yet, so you were not able to re-provision the sync group at the same time.

May I know whether you are still experiencing this problem? If yet could you please provide the latest error log? I'll update the answer then.